# running py file with arguments as after pip install

Tags: python

I would like to modify this tool for text cleaning:
https://github.com/JonathanReeve/chapterize

I work in cloud9. When I install this useful tool by :

```
sudo pip3 install chapterize
```

and then run it on txt file:

```
chapterize 10004.txt --nochapters
```

it works with no error
but when I copied chapterize.py to cloud9 environment from here:
https://github.com/JonathanReeve/chapterize/blob/master/chapterize/chapterize.py
and run:

```
python chapterize.py 10004.txt --nochapters
```

I receive following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "chapterize.py", line 259, in <module>
cli()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in 
__call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in 
 main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in 
invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in 
invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "chapterize.py", line 32, in cli
bookObj = Book(book, nochapters, stats)
File "chapterize.py", line 38, in __init__
self.contents = self.getContents()
File "chapterize.py", line 60, in getContents
with open(self.filename, errors='ignore') as f:
TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What is wrong? Why I cannot run it like this? I have not modified the source code in any way..

Comment: You're using a different version of Python than the one specified in the hashbang. Try `python3 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running Python 2.

The `errors` parameter in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is present in Python 3.

Try `python3 chapterize.py 10004.txt --nochapters`